# EditText converting decimal to exponential

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am storing a value in database as `0.0004` and displaying the same in `EditText` but in edittext it as showing as `4.0E-4` tried a lot of things nothing seems to work for me.

Storing value in database is fine but when coming to edittext display it is wrong.

What I have tried:

1. Increased the size of edit text but didn't solve the problem.
2. Followed below process

   ```
   DecimalFormat FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("0.####");

    textvalue.setText(REAL_FORMATTER.format(new_percent.getLong(new_percent.getColumnIndex(bt.column2))));
   ```

but the result is same no chage.

Can any one help to solve this..I want the display in edit text as `0.0004` not as `4.0E-4`

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved as below.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(Cursor.getDouble(Cursor.getColumnIndex(bt.column2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving pattern to the `BigDecimal` just send directly the value to the constructor parameter.

**example:**

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("4.0E-4");

int ints= number.intValue(); //BigDecimal to integer

double doubles= number.doubleValue(); //BigDecimal to double
```

Comment: But I am using EditText to view the value... Also in database I have no issues with the value..

Comment: Still not getting the result... Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Why you retrieve **0.0004** value with the **getLong** mehod?

As I suppose, you store the **0.0004** in a database in a **REAL** column type,
so you should retrieve this with **getDouble**.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.####");
textValue.setText(
  formatter.format(
    new_percent.getDouble(
      new_percent.getColumnIndexOrThrow(bt.column2))));
```

Comment: Good catch thanks... but unfortunately result is same after changing to `Double`.